# Struggling to show image with ACF WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I've been trying to display an image with ACF code and have just got it working, but I can't work out why some code works and some doesn't.

```
if(get_row_layout() == 'bq_product'):
        $image = the_sub_field('affiliate_image');
        $affiliate_url = the_sub_field('affiliate_url');
                
        
        ?><img src="<?php echo $image ?>"/><?php //This line doesn't work and just displays the raw URL on the front end
        ?><img src="<?php the_sub_field('affiliate_image') ?>"/><?php //This line works and shows the image
        ?><a href="<?php $affiliate_url ?>">Link</a> //Similarly, this line doesn't use the URL set in affiliate_url, but does if I pass "the_sub_field('affiliate_url')"
```

How do I use the variable names within the image src without it just showing the raw URL on the front end?

I've tried using "get_sub_field" variations but they don't seem to make a difference.

Comment: the_sub_field echoes automatically - get_sub_field makes you able to save it as variables.  - You also need to make sure, what you have your unage fields return - array, ID or URL.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as [@Stender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244684/stender) commented, attempting to store variables using ACF `the_sub_field()` will not work.

Use `get_sub_field()` instead to store returned ACF field data to your variables.

Then access variable data based on what you have set the ACF fields to return with... `array`, `ID` or `URL`

1. See example below (based on `affiliate_image` ACF field return format `URL`)

```php
// if row layout is 'bq_product'
if(get_row_layout() == 'bq_product'):
 
    // sub field vars
    $affiliate_image  = get_sub_field('affiliate_image');
    $affiliate_url    = get_sub_field('affiliate_url');
                
    // if $affiliate_image variable is not boolean false    
    if($image) {
        echo '<img src="' . $affiliate_image . '" alt="" />';
    }

    // if $affiliate_url is not boolean false
    if($affiliate_url) {
        echo '<a href="' . $affiliate_url . '">Link</a>';
    }

endif;
```

2. See example below (based on `affiliate_image` ACF field return format `array`)

```php
// if row layout is 'bq_product'
if(get_row_layout() == 'bq_product'):
 
    // sub field vars
    $affiliate_image  = get_sub_field('affiliate_image');
    $affiliate_url    = get_sub_field('affiliate_url');

    // use this to dump $affiliate_image array to see data for image sizes etc
    // echo '<pre>' . print_r($affiliate_image, true) . '</pre>';
         
    // if $affiliate_image variable is array       
    if(is_array($affiliate_image) {
        echo '<img src="' . $affiliate_image['url'] . '" alt="' . $affiliate_image['alt'] . '" />';
    }

    // if $affiliate_url is not boolean false
    if($affiliate_url) {
        echo '<a href="' . $affiliate_url . '">Link</a>';
    }

endif;
```